Hypergeometric approximation of herd sensitivity and its non-linear nature
I have recently been exploring the use of the equation described in Cannon 2001 paper "Sense and Sensitivity" on herd sensitivity (love the name).


I have been looking to test a hypothetical herd with two different protocols (each protocol has a different test sensitivity), and then hoping to combine the results of the two testing protocols for one herd sensitivity. I calculated two herd sensitivities and then combined them in parallel. One problem I'm trying to wrap my head around is that I believe there is a non-linear component that I am missing that creates a loss in herd sensitivity beyond that which is explained by just differences in test sensitivity. I further explored this by calculating the herd sensitivity of a 300 animal herd testing 100 animals and then calculating two herd sensitivities of testing 50 animals (with the same test sensitivity) and combining them in parallel. So, despite testing the same overall number of animals (100) with the same test sensitivity I got a lower herd sensitivity. I suppose this makes sense given the curve of herd sensitivity.

However I am struggling to find a way to quantify or estimate this "loss" of herd sensitivity, as it would be useful to know how much a herd sensitivity decreases just due to the adoption of the different less sensitive testing protocols. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

That equation is very small and hard to read. You could retype it to make it easier for the reader?

Apologies, I've reposted the pictures, hope that helps!
